# Restore Windows desktop icon positions after screen resolution change

Tags: windows-7, resolution, icons, desktop-icons

After changing the graphics card in my computer, Windows 7 automatically changed the screen resolution to *800 x 600*. I were able to change it back to *1920 x 1200* without any restart. However, the order of the icons on the desktop is totally messed up (Before, the icons were manually arranged all over the desktop, now they are all distributed on the left side).

How can I restore the arrangement of the icons on the desktop?

Unfortunately, I have no backup at hand. Tools that allow to save and restore the icon position won't help, because the icon position is already changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the command prompt (cmd) as an administrator and execute the following code line by line:

```
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
start explorer.exe
```

After the first command, all icons and windows will disappear (except for the cmd windows). After executing the second command, they will come back (hopefully in the correct arrangement).

Note that this solution won't work if the wrong arrangement of the icons has already been saved. This would occur if you have already logged out/restarted your system after the icons were in the wrong order or if you would have right clicked on the desktop and selected *Refresh*.